# SSIS - How to union many files from several folders with a mask

Tags: ssis, union

I'm trying to union several files (put one file under another) based on a name mask. This is easily achievable when all files are in the same folder using a "for each loop/for each file enumerator" container at the control flow level.
My concern is how can I achieve that if my files are in different folders, each with his own mask? in other words, can I have something like the "for each loop/for each file enumerator" container to retrieve the file name at the data flow level.

Thanks

Comment: Could you perhaps explain better what you are attempting to do. Union many files and SSIS could mean lots of things. Feel free to view the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section for tips on making an effective question

Comment: Have you tried ticking "Traverse Subfolders"?

Comment: the files have different mask.

Comment: Are you saying files in Folder ABC\DEF are *.txt and files in ABC\ZZZ are *.csv?

Comment: all files are *.csv but the name of file 1 is "AAA.31122019.csv" and file 2: "BBB.31122019.csv" and file 3: "BLABLA.01032020.csv". In addition, each file is in a different folder. Fortunately, all files have the same layout.

Comment: Is there a requirement to exclude other files? In this case I suggest you pre-process the folders and stage the required files in a single folder

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: Yes, some files must be excluded. Your approach is worth considering. Any suggestion to achieve that?

Comment: Personally I would write powershell to do the required and call that from SSIS. Some prefer to use a C# script task.